# import python module/packge into remote machine

Tags: python, virtualbox

I have setup virtual box and install package (WxPython) into virtual machine and doing programming for learning wxpython and Python. we connect into remote machine using putty in windows and ssh in virtual box.
I want to do some experiment/analysis with exiting code using WxPython But we do not have permission to install  python package into remote machine. if I raise ticket package to install package towards IT team it require lot of business justification.

As it is my personal interest, I do not have any business reason

is it possible,can I access wxPython package into remote machine which is installed into virtual box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not in any way associated with the tool I am going to suggest. I have used [Vagrant](http://www.vagrantup.com) with VirtualBox and it has worked fine for me.

The code is in a folder which is accessible from both Virtual as well as Base machine.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not install it locally on the remote machine, and not globally, then just export that python path?